特定の期間内のカウント
ある期間における人数をカウントしようとしています。
以下のテーブルがあります。



ID
start
end




1
20240101
20240220


2
20240201
20240331


3
20240301
20240431


4
20240301
20240630


5
20240401
20240630



テーブル作成クエリ
create table emp(id text primary key,start text not null,end text not null);

データ投入
insert into emp(id, start , end) values(1, '20240101', '20240220');
insert into emp(id, start , end) values(2, '20240201', '20240331');
insert into emp(id, start , end) values(3, '20240301', '20240431');
insert into emp(id, start , end) values(4, '20240301', '20240630');
insert into emp(id, start , end) values(5, '20240401', '20240630');

この表から最終的に以下の結果を得る場合、どのようなクエリを書けばいいでしょうか？
idは従業員IDで、その従業員が各月にどれだけ存在しているか　を確認しようとしています。



MONTH
COUNTS




202401
1


202402
2


202403
3


202404
3


202405
2


202406
2




以下二つのクエリにて動作確認できました。
create table test_cl as
with recursive calendar(calendar_date) as (
select
date('2024-01-01') as calendar_date
union all
select
date(calendar_date,'+1 month') ascalendar_date
from calendar
where
calendar_date < date('2024-06-30')
)
select calendar_date from calendar
;

with test as (
select
replace(substr(a.calendar_date, 1, 7),'-','') as month,b.id,b.start,b.end
from test_cl as a cross join emp as b
where month >= substr(b.start, 1, 6) and month <= substr(b.end, 1, 6)
order by id,start
)
select month,count(distinct id) as counts
from test
group by month
order by month
;

